# How can I bind the correct user to the correct session when storing a token in redis?

Tags: python, redis, jwt, fastapi

Help me understand how user sessions work based on JWT. Im using fastapi with static Jinja Template for now. But I think the question is not about a specific framework, but about the logic of the whole.
Now I have implemented the following functionality:
When a user logs in, a JWT is created which is written to redis in the following form

```
{
'SOMe_KEY' : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0b3B0YWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNDI2NDIwODAwLCJodHRwOi8vdG9wdGFsLmNvbS9qd3RfY2xhaW1zL2lzX2FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJjb21wYW55IjoiVG9wdGFsIiwiYXdlc29tZSI6dHJ1ZX0.yRQYnWzskCZUxPwaQupWkiUzKELZ49eM7oWxAQK_ZXw
}
```

The token has the necessary information about the user: id, email, permission_type

now, as i understand it, every request which should check for authorization should either check if the user has a session or redirect to the log_in page

**My question:**
How to match a user with a token in redis, this query here

```
session = await redis_cache.get('SOMe_KEY')
```

How to understand which key to pass in the `get('SOMe_KEY')` query
And which key to use when generating a token record in the database.
I.e. now i have hardcode for one user, there is a session key in the database and i pass the same key in the query. But what should be the logic for a large quantity of users?

Code sample

```
@router.post('/sign-in')
async def sign_in(
        user_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
        service: AuthService = Depends(),
):
    token = await service.authenticate_user(
        user_data.username,
        user_data.password
    )
    await redis_cache.set('SOMe_KEY', token)

@router.get("/private")
def read_private(username: str = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return {"username": username, "private": "get some private data"}

async def get_current_user():
    try:
        session = await redis_cache.get('SOMe_KEY')
        payload = jwt.decode(
            session,
            config('JWT_SECRET'),
            algorithms=config('JWT_ALGORITHM'),
        )
        return payload['user']
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Invalid authentication"
        )
```

Comment: Usually, the JWT is sent with every client request, there is not really any need to save it additionally in a database.

Comment: But any way we need to save token in cookie or local storage, save token in redis is an alternative. In that case, how does the client understand what exactly token to request in Redis?

Comment: `SOMe_KEY` should be something that identifies the user, like: user_id, email address ... whatever. The unique identifier can be used as Redis key and needs to be present in the JWT as well. So you would decode the JWT first and lookup for the key in Redis afterwards.

Comment: This is good for answering the question of which key to use when writing a token to redis. What remains to be clarified is how to know which key to send to redis when executing a GET query. where to get it from ?

Comment: Usually from a cookie. If you're using JWT there is no need to store it in Redis, since you sign the JWT to authenticate that it is valid and identifies a user properly. However, if you instead use a regular session token (random string with a decent size), you can use that token as the key in redis, and have the user id be the value. That gives you which user account this user is authenticated as back.

Comment: Yes. I think I formulated my question wrong because I didn't really understand the topic. Now I understand that I don't need JWT at all, I need a session in redis with a **session_id** key which is stored in a cookie. When I run a `GET` query in redis , the **session_id** is used as a key to matching. Maurice Meyer, MatsLindh  thanks for your help.